# Read strings Array from javascript file in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a file countries.js which contains an array of countries and I would like to read and use this in my rails app also as an array of strings.

The content of js file:

```
export default [
 'United States',
 'Canada',
  ...
 ];
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you already tried to accomplish this task?

Comment: @jmizv I tried to read the file and iterate over the lines, but could not get the final rest:
['United States', 'Canada', ..]

Comment: @amir.algazi : In this case, you should show your code, because your approach, if done correctly, might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 countries = File.read('countries.js')

 countries.gsub(/export default/,"").
 split("\n").map{|c|c.gsub(/[^a-z A-Z]/,"")}.
 map(&:strip).
 reject(&:empty?)
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to convert this file to a JSON file.

```
contries = File.read('countries.json')
countries = JSON.parse(countries)
```

You might need to further parse it with JSON so that you can convert string to a collection data structure.